# Is Log stream compression enabled by default for asynchronous replicas in Distributed Availability groups as well?

Tags: sql-server, distributed-availability-groups

I am seeding a database using distributed availability group. Seeding is automatic but synchronization mode is asynchronous. Log stream compression for automatic seeding is NOT enabled via TF 9567. Value for 'is_compression_enabled' in DMV 'sys.dm_hadr_physical_seeding_stats' is showing 0 during seeding operation.

As per MS documentation '*Log stream compression is enabled by default for asynchronous replicas.*' According to this, shouldn't log stream compression be enabled by default for this seeding operation? That's why I got this question if this is same behavior for Distributed availability groups also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per MS documentation 'Log stream compression is enabled by default for asynchronous replicas.'

This is when the Async replicas are functioning as part of AG post AG configuration, if you see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/tune-compression-for-availability-group?view=sql-server-ver15) it says enabled for `Asynchronous- commit replicas`. During automatic seeding no matter sync or async replica the log compression is disabled by default. To enable it as you know you have to enable the trace flag 9567.

Hope this is clear